# Как объединить одинаковое значение одного массива с одинаковым ключом другого?

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть два массива:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id_product_attribute' => '123',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id_product_attribute' => '122',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id_product_attribute' => '118',
  )
)

array (
  123 => 
  array (
    'prices' => 
    array (
      'a' => 146.9,
      'b' => true,
      'c' => '-5',
    ),
  ),
  122 => 
  array (
    'prices' => 
    array (
      'a' => 257.9,
      'b' => true,
      'c' => '-8',
    ),
  ),
  118 => 
  array (
    'prices' => 
    array (
      'a' => 479.9,
      'b' => true,
      'c' => '-20',
    ),
  )
)
```

Каким способом мне нужно проверить значение первого массива и добавить ключ со второго если они совпадают?
Чтобы это было так

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id_product_attribute' => '123',
    'prices' => 
    array (
      'a' => 146.9,
      'b' => true,
      'c' => '-5',
    )
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id_product_attribute' => '122',
    'prices' => 
    array (
      'a' => 257.9,
      'b' => true,
      'c' => '-8',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id_product_attribute' => '118',
    'prices' => 
    array (
      'a' => 479.9,
      'b' => true,
      'c' => '-20',
    ),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так должно сработать:

```
array_walk($array1, function(&$product) use ($array2) {
    $product_id = $product['id_product_attribute'];

    if (isset($array2[$product_id]['prices'])) {
        $product['prices'] = $array2[$product_id]['prices'];
    }
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Сделал ответ чуть более развёрнутым. Хотя это похоже на лишнюю формальность.

Comment: Да, это то что нужно) Спасибо тебе!

Answer (score 0):

Для начала напишите код. Какой-то код у вас наверное уже написан, но речь не о нём. Напишите код, который создаёт первый массив из вашего примера. Начните с одного элемента.

```php
<?php

$products = [
    [
        'id_product_attribute' => '123',
    ],
];

var_dump($products);
```

Сохраните это в файл test.php и запустите из консоли `php test.php`. Запускать код с экспериментами очень важно. Даже в таком простом коде могут быть ошибки, полезно узнать об этом заранее.

Окей. Теперь вы хотите добавить во вложенный массив `prices`. Как это сделать? Допустим `prices` у вас уже есть.

```php
<?php

$products = [
    [
        'id_product_attribute' => '123',
    ],
];
$products[0]['prices'] = ['a' => 146.9, 'b' => true, 'c' => '-5'];

var_dump($products);
```

Запустите. Работает? Отлично, тогда едем дальше. Элементов $products может быть несколько, чтобы каждому добавить `prices` можно использовать циклы. Напишите код с циклом.

```php
<?php

$products = [
    [
        'id_product_attribute' => '123',
    ],
    [
        'id_product_attribute' => '122',
    ],
];

foreach ($products as &$product) {
    $product['prices'] = ['a' => 146.9, 'b' => true, 'c' => '-5'];  
}

var_dump($products);
```

Надеюсь вы знаете, что это за [&](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) такой в коде. Разберитесь как менять значения массива в цикле, напишите код и обязательно убедитесь, что он работает.

Осталось немного. Цены у вас в отдельном массиве с ключами, которые могут совпадать со значениями `id_product_attribute`. Зная ключ, можно получить значение. Добавьте в код массив с ценами и установите продуктам соответствующие `prices`. Когда закончите, обязательно запустите код и убедитесь, что он работает как надо.

Обратите внимание, что код должен работать правильно и в том случае, если в массиве цен нет подходящего ключа. Для проверки существования значения можно использовать [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php).

---

Из этого вы должны понять 3 важные вещи:

1. php.net -- отличный источник информации о PHP, там много примеров, которые помогут вам понять как что работает.
2. Если вы столкнулись с трудностями, изолируйте проблему -- создайте отдельный тестовый файлик и упростите задачу до тривиальной, затем усложняйте, пока не получите решение. Не пытайтесь экспериментировать в рабочем коде, там может быть много деталей, которые вас запутают.
3. Всегда запускайте код, чтобы убедится, что он работает так, как вы ожидаете. Запускайте код как можно раньше и запускайте код как можно чаще.